# Specify language of Comment using Entity Translation?

Tags: 7, organic-groups, comments, i18n-l10n

I'm building a site with multilingual support using Entity Translation. It is allowing authors to specify a language when creating a node, but there's no way to specify language when commenting on a node.

In Configuration > Entity translation, the Comment item is checked in the Translatable Entity Types section.

In Structure > Content Types > Post, I see tabs for Comment Fields, and Comment Display, but language is not one of the options.

I have been looking into the form_comment_form_alter hook, but so far have had no success with that.

In the Permissions panel, I confirmed that Administrator has "Translate entities of type Comment" checked. Even when editing a comment as admin, there is no option to translate.

The site uses Organic Groups 7.x-2.5, if that could influence this problem. The OG Post content type is the main one I'm trying to get fully functional.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal natural way would be to show comments for different languages separately.

For example If you have a node in English and Spanish. Drupal natural way would be to show comments for en/es translation separately (attached to en/es content).

If you are looking for language field you can use [Language field](https://drupal.org/project/languagefield) module...

> This module creates a Language Field that combines Drupal 7's Field
>   list options and Internal language list.
>
> This is used to simply collect language data.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. For my use case, I was hoping to have comments of all languages on the same page, with translations available without leaving the main node.